# UICollection Cell doesn't start from zero index for new section

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, storyboard, uicollectionviewcell

I have written a code for showing cells in different sections. But when I run the code, in a new section, cell is at next position from where previous cell was displayed.

```
let cell: EPOSProductCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "productCell", for: indexPath) as! EPOSProductCollectionViewCell

cell.productImage.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(urlString: menuResponse?.data?[indexPath.section].products?[indexPath.item].image ?? "") 
cell.productName.text = menuResponse?.data?[indexPath.section].products?[indexPath.item].name ?? ""

if menuResponse?.data?[indexPath.section].products?[indexPath.item].spiceLevel != nil {
    // ...
} else {
    cell.spiceLevelIcon.isHidden = true
}

return cell
```

**For section** my code is as follows:

```
let sectionHeader = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "sectionHeader", for: indexPath) as! EPOSMenuCollectionReusableView
sectionHeader.sectionHeaderTitle.text = menuResponse?.data[indexPath.section].name

return sectionHeader
```

Section is created from Storyboard

This issue occurs in landscape mode and only when there is one item in any given section.

[Here is the picture for understanding the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qITnU.png)

Comment: If my memory serves me right, that's the default behaviour of UICollectionViewLayout if there is only one item. Use a custom layout?

Comment: do a print statement after your dequeue... with print(indexPath.section, "- " indexPath,item) and you will see it starts at index 0. I am pretty sure the error is in your code and if you don't show us more code we cannot help you....

Comment: @Chris this is the whole code.
`func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
 return self.menuList?.data?.count ?? 0
}`

`func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return self.menuList?.data?[section].products?.count ?? 0
}`
This is the complete code. There is nothing else

Comment: did you implement the print statement?

Comment: Yes I did. It showed 0-0 , 0-1 and 1-0.....

Comment: @Chris I just realised that this issue occurs only in landscape mode and as I am developing application for iPad and specifically for landscape, that is why i am getting this issue.

P.S still not able to find any solution